# Can I write linux GPIO interrupt handler using bash

Tags: linux, bash, interrupt, interrupt-handling, gpio

I know I can use those bash commands to deal with GPIO value and the status.

```
echo "4" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value
echo in > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
echo falling > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/edge
```

I can set GPIO 17 as a interrupt pin by bash command now,
but can someone tell me how to write a interrupt handler using bash.

Answer (score 1):

[Implementing GPIO event handlers requires access to the `poll()` syscall](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt); bash doesn't provide any way to invoke this, so the answer is no: You can't implement GPIO handlers in pure bash with no other language involved.

A small shim written in a more capable language that invokes a callback written in shell, by contrast, should be a straightforward exercise.

Comment: Hi Charles, can I implement GPIO interrupt in pure user level(C or C++)? I found most people are writing a linux driver to do that.

Comment: @KingofNerd, absolutely, you can. Read the link.